# HTTP Status 404, The requested resource () is not available spring maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am getting "The requested resource () is not available" message in the browser while running the code. I have created the controller but not implemented it as this is just a jsp page with hello world message. Please help me in this as I am new to it.

web.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MavenProject</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                </listener-class>
    </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml File:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MavenProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servletapi.version>3.0.1</servletapi.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- compile only, deployed container will provide this -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
        <configuration>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
            <webApp>
                <contextPath>/spring3</contextPath>
            </webApp>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <!-- configure Eclipse workspace --> 
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            <wtpContextName>spring3</wtpContextName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/MavenProject</path>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

index.jsp File:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!!!!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your request url?

Comment: I right click on the project -> Run As - > Run on server. The url was http://localhost:8080/MavenProject/

Comment: Have you created any controller class?

Comment: Yes, I have created BaseController Class but did not write any code in it as I am not using it. First I want to print Hello World in index.jsp page.